# Modified RSA Proving $x^{(p-1)(q-1)/\gcd(p-1,q-1)} \equiv 1 \mod pq$

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

In RSA, we use $ab \equiv 1 \mod \varphi(n)$ for $n=pq$ product of distinct odd primes. In an exercise of Stinson's book, Cryptography : Theory and Practise, it is said that if we change $\varphi(n)$ to $\lambda(n)=\frac{(p-1)(q-1)}{\gcd(p-1,q-1)}$, we are still able to do the same encryption and decryption. How can we prove this? I am still unable see why this is true. And also, can we generalise to other $n$ which is not product of two distinct odd primes? Thank you.

Comment: Look up Carmichael's function.  The proof of RSA goes through just fine if $\lambda$ is used in place of $\varphi$.  This is related to the fact that the exponent of an abelian group is a finer invariant than its order.

Comment: the main thing is that $\lambda(n) = \operatorname{lcm} (p-1,q-1) $

Comment: @Randall thank you for your comment, how can I prove that Carmichael's function is the exponent of abelian group?

Comment: It's pretty direct from known facts about the exponent of an abelian group.  But Will Jagy's comment is the real meat of the matter.

Comment: @Will Jagy how to prove that $\text{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$ is exponent of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}^{*}$?

Comment: @LaurencePW you can get this easily from the chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: @Randall okay, thank you for your answer